# Getting exception details

Tags: python

I know I can catch exceptions in python like:

```
try:
    with open('file.log') as file:
        read_data = file.read()
except:
    print('Exception!')
```

But how to get exception type or error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    with open('file.log') as file:
        read_data = file.read()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

You have to cast the Exception to a variable. This and more is in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).